# $\{\,x \in I: \phi'(x)$ $\text{does not exist}\,\}$ is at most countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an interval.

If $\phi$ is convex,  then $\{\,x \in I: \phi'(x)$ $\text{does not exist}\,\}$ is at most countable.

An idea please.

Comment: You can also refere to this website : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141624/construction-of-a-convex-function-nondifferentiable-on-a-countable-set

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ inside $I=[a,b]$, we have $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)}{h}=\inf\left\{\,\frac{\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)}{h}\Biggm| h>0\,\right\} \ge\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(a)}{x-a}$$
hence the right derivative $\delta_+\phi$ certainly exists everywhere. Similar for the left derivative $\delta_-\phi$. Also, $x_1<x_2$ implies $\delta_-\phi(x_1)\le \delta_+\phi(x_1)\le \delta_-\phi(x_2)$. Thus with any point $x$ we can associate an open interval $I_x:=(\delta_-\phi(x)\le \delta_+\phi(x))$ with the property that $\delta_\pm(y)\ne I_x$ for any $y$. Also, $x_1\ne x_2$ implies $I_{x_1}\cap I_{x_2}=\emptyset$. Therefore, at most countably many of the $I_x$ can be nonempty (as each nonempty contains a rational). But $I_x=\emptyset$ means that $\delta_-\phi(x)=\delta_+\phi(x)=\phi'(x)$.